# Space Engineers Not Installing From Disc

Tags: steam, space-engineers

(Originally from Steam Discussion:
http://steamcommunity.com/app/244850/discussions/6/618453594741594824/)

I got the retail version of Space Engineers (Limited Edition) and put it into my computer. The instruction sheet that came with the game says that when I open the menu there should be some installation instructions. The only options that came up were "Redeem Steam Key", "Install Miner Wars", "Artwork" and "Soundtrack". I have redeemed the steam key, but there is no option to install it. Is there a way to do it from the disc, or do I have to download it?

EDIT: I have tried both ways of installing from disc (Using the "Run [Windows Function]" feature and the "Restore From Disc [Steam Function]") but both do not work. Trying to do it with "Run" just opens steam, does nothing else. But using "Restore", I cannot do it as it says there is no back-up. Is Space Engineers a game that HAS to be downloaded?

Comment: Do you think you could tell me what's on the disk; the folder structure? (It could be that you're restoring from the wrong location, ie. the CD's root directory)

Comment: There is A "Bonus" folder, containing music and artwork for the limited edition. There is "CD Components", those are the only folders. But in steam, when I try to "restore" from the CD components, there are no backups. I have also tried by just selecting the disc drive in the "restore" feature, still no luck.

Comment: Perhaps it is intended that you download it off Steam. | I could be completely wrong, since I'm guessing and don't actually have a copy of it.

Answer (score 2):

After you activated the key, just open your Steam library and download the game. It's only about 1.5 gigabytes, and this will be the cleanest and simplest way, since the only important part of your retail copy is the key it included, which you said you redeemed.

Comment: I don't get why they would release a retail copy of a game, just so you have to download it. Thanks for the reply, anyway.

Comment: Having to download the game after installing it from disk (either because the game doesn't fit or because there's since been updates) is pretty much the norm with retail Steam games. The only important thing is the key which licenses it to your account. I can still see how some people might like to have a physical box for the game on their shelf, which may be one point to having a retail box.